# Is tf.contrib.layers.flatten(x) the same as tf.reshape(x, [n, 1])?

Tags: tensorflow

I was just wondering whether `tf.contrib.layers.flatten(x)` is  the same as `tf.reshape(x, [n, 1])`? Anyone has ideas about this?

Comment: Flatten collapses all the dimensions except for the batch size. `[bs, n, m, k] -> [bs, n*m*k]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/15bd614fedc20d229f3e97a99e0748136ba4852c/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py#L361) of [`tf.layers.flatten()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/python/tf/layers/flatten) reveals the answer. It is equivalent to the following:

```
flattened = tf.reshape(x, [tf.shape(x)[0], -1])
```